# Not drawing at desired position in "Processing"

Tags: processing, mouse

I am trying to draw at one place by dragging a mouse (for example, a circle in left upper quadrant) and have the figure appear at 4 places around center of canvas (including one right under the mouse cursor). I have tried following code:

```java
int x=0;
int y=0;

void setup(){
   size(400, 400);  
   background(255); 
   translate(width/2, height/2); 
}
void draw() {
}

void mouseDragged(){
    translate(width/2, height/2); 

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
      rotate(PI/2); 
      x= mouseX ; y=mouseY;
      line(x, y, mouseX, mouseY);
    }
  }
```

However, the figure does not get drawn under the mouse cursor. If I am very close to upper left corner, the lines get drawn at center of canvas.

Secondly, a total of 5 figures get drawn instead of 4 as I am trying. If I draw near left upper corner, the unwanted figure appears at right lower corner of canvas. This unwanted figure is fainter than other figures.

Where are the errors and how can both these problems be corrected? I want to achieve this with rotate commands (rotating around center of canvas), though I saw that I can also use translate command to draw at 4 places on canvas.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your points are under the mouse because you're translating the canvas (to `width/2, height/2`) before drawing your points, but you're using `mouseX, mouseY` to draw them. Think of `mouseX, mouseY` as the X and Y distance from the upper-left corner. If you want a point to be under the mouse, you have to use the distance from the point you translated to!

In other words, instead of this:

```
x = mouseX; 
y = mouseY;
```

You want this:

```
x = width/2 - mouseX; 
y = height/2 - mouseY;
```

As for the extra point being drawn, that seems to be a side-effect of using the `mouseDragged()` function. Something strange is going on there, but you can get around this problem by just using the `draw()` function and the `mousePressed` variable instead of the `mouseDragged()` function.

**Edit:** I switched the order they should be in. Check out my answer to your [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971432/not-drawing-under-the-mouse-in-processing) for a better explanation.

Comment: "Something strange is going on there" : does that mean its a bug in this otherwise excellent software?

Comment: @mso Honestly I don't know. It does seem a little buggy, but I haven't spent enough time with it to say for sure. Might want to compare behaviors using different renderers, or try printing out exactly which extra points get rendered- there seem to be fewer of them than the regular points, which might be a sign.