# Not drawing under the mouse in "Processing"

Tags: processing, mouse, draw

I want to draw at one place by dragging the mouse and have the line drawn at 3 places around the center of canvas, including one under the cursor itself. I am using following code which does draw 3 lines but none of them is under the mouse cursor:

```java
void setup(){
   size(300, 300); }

void draw() {
  translate(width/2, height/2); 
  if(mousePressed)
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
      line(width/2 -mouseX,  height/2 -mouseY, 
           width/2 -pmouseX, height/2 -pmouseY);
      rotate(2*PI/3);  }}
```

How can I correct this code so that one drawing is right under mouse cursor and other 2 are rotated accordingly?

Comment: Just a heads up, it's a little bit rude to delete questions after people take the time to answer them. Makes it less likely people will help you in the future. :(

Comment: It was a stupid mistake for which a short comment would have been sufficient. I tried now to see if I could undelete it but it is no more available. I have found many of your other posts also very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think about where your points are in relation to your `translate()` and `rotate()` calls.

First you translate, so the origin is in the center of the screen instead of in the upper-left corner. So all of your points need to be relative to the center instead of relative to the upper-left corner.

To debug this, I'd start by getting rid of the `for` loop and simply drawing a single point, or a single line:

```
void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
}

void draw() {
  translate(width/2, height/2); 
  if (mousePressed) {
    line(width/2 -mouseX,  height/2 -mouseY, 
      width/2 -pmouseX, height/2 -pmouseY);
  }
}
```

You'll see that this is off, which means your logic for computing the line's position is wrong. You can play with this to notice a pattern, and you can think about some example points.

The center point is `150,150`. So if the mouse is at `160,160`, what position should we draw the point? Remember it's relative to `150,150`, so `160,160` becomes `10,10`.

In other words, we're subtracting the center from the mouse to figure out where to draw the point.

But your code subtracts the mouse from the center, which is backwards.

If you have similar problems in the future, I highly suggest going through the process of thinking of example points and figuring out where they should go. Graph paper is your best friend with stuff like this.

Note: I realize that you're basing your code off my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949018/not-drawing-at-desired-position-in-processing), so that's my bad. I got the order wrong, but it didn't matter in your other question because you were translating 4 times (so the mouse cursor got covered anyway).